# Cannot resolve this error Stray start tag html

Tags: html, wordpress

**Please help me on this.
I am not able to resolve this error using [https://validator.w3.org/]

I have tried many solutions even from stackoverflow suggestions but it is not working for me.**

> Stray start tag html.
>       From line 3, column 2; to line 3, column 34
>       ption.">↩ ↩

```
/*here is my html code*/

<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description.">
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en" class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><html lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><html lang="en-US"><![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user scalable=no">
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>
        <?php wp_title(''); ?>
        <?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' :'; } ?>
        <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
    </title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>


    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
       ......
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like it is catching your php tags, you'll want to run the validator over the actual html output (i.e. View Source in browser).

Comment: Please tell me what do i need to change in this code?

Comment: as already mentioned above, a line such as `<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">` won't validate since it's not valid html. load the site on a browser and use the generated html instead (view source > select all > copy)

also you shouldn't add scripts/styles like this, take a look [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/)